# How to return a row count

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm having trouble getting the row counts back from a MySQL query in PHP.

A link to the [test page](http://www.hokosounds.com/ajaxTest.html) and the PHP code is as follows:

```
<?php 

$con=* TESTED AND WORKING *

// Check connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


$retDiv = "";

$counter = 0;

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM  `store` ORDER BY  `num` DESC ");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    if ($counter>=5)
    {   
        break;
    }
    else
    {   
        $retDiv = "<div id=\"hs" . $row['num'] . "\" class=\"store-item " . $row['Artist'] . "\">\n";
        $retDiv = $retDiv . "<div id=\"". $row['Release'] . "-title\" class=\"album-title\">\n";
        $retDiv = $retDiv . "<h1 align=\"center\" style=\"text-transform:uppercase;\">" . $row['Release'] . "</h1></br>\n";
        $retDiv = $retDiv . "<h3 align=\"center\">" . $row['ReleaseName'] . "</h3>\n";
        $retDiv = $retDiv . "</div>\n";
        $retDiv = $retDiv . "<div id=\"" . $row['Release'] . "-description\" class=\"description\">\n";
        $retDiv = $retDiv . "<table width=\"100%\">\n";
        $retDiv = $retDiv . "<td width=\"50%\" style=\"padding-left:57px;padding-right:57px;padding-top:57px;padding-bottom:20px;\">\n";
        $retDiv = $retDiv . "<a id=\"" . $row['Release'] . "DivLink\" href=\"javascript:;\" onmousedown=\"toggleDivStore('" . $row['Release'] . "-expand','" . $row['Release'] . "DivLink','" . $row['Release'] . "','" . $row['Release'] . "b','" . $row['Release'] . "')\"><img name=\"" . $row['Release'] . "-art\" src = \"images/" . $row['Release'] . ".jpg\" class=\"album-art\" onmouseover=\"this.src='images/" . $row['Release'] . "b.jpg'\" onmouseout=\"this.src='images/" . $row['Release'] . ".jpg'\"></a>\n";
        $retDiv = $retDiv . "<td width=\"50%\" style=\"padding:20px;padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:0px;\">\n";
        $retDiv = $retDiv . "<p style=\"\">" . $row['Description'] . "</p>\n";
        $retDiv = $retDiv . "</td>\n";
        $retDiv = $retDiv . "</table>\n";
        $retDiv = $retDiv . "</div>\n";
        $retDiv = $retDiv . "<div class=\"album-expand\" id=\"RELEASE-expand\" style=\"display:none;\">\n";
        $retDiv = $retDiv . "</div>\n";
        $retDiv = $retDiv . "<div =\"" . $row['Release'] . "PaypalContainer\" class=\"album-paypal-container\">\n";
        $retDiv = $retDiv . $row['Paypal1'];
        $retDiv = $retDiv . "</div>\n";
        $retDiv = $retDiv . "</div>\n";

        echo $retDiv;
    }
    $counter = $counter+1;
}


echo "<div id=\"retNum\"><script type=\"text/javascript\">numReleases =" . $num_rows . ";numPages=Math.ceil(numReleases/5)-1;</SCRIPT></div>";

mysqli_close($con);
```

How to return the row count as `$num_rows` to the `retNum` Javascript?

Comment: `mysql_num_rows($result);` use `mysqli_num_rows($result);`

Comment: thank you! should i delete this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing mysqli (note the `i`) and mysql (note the **LACK** of an i). The two libraries and function bodies are **NOT** interoperable:

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
                 ^--- missing an `i` here
```

Comment: thanks marc! should i delete this question? first time posting sorry for a dumb question. i didnt know there was a difference

Comment: it's up to you. deleting a question that's got answers dings your account somewhat, though.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using mysqli_query() method to get the result set from the database, the number of rows from the result can be obtained by calling mysqli_num_rows() method which takes the mysqli_result set as the argument and do not use mysql_num_rows(). Check [mysqli_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using PHP logic to break out, why not add "LIMIT 5" to your sql query?

Comment: i tried that but i like to return the total number of rows in the table to return to the javascript. i suppose i could use a count separately though. thanks for your input!

Comment: In order to reduce the load on the MySql server, you could use "SELECT count(*) FROM  `store`" to obtain the total number of records, then use the LIMIT clause to restrict subsequent pages.